# Determining Viability of Chi-squared for Feature Selection

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, chi-squared

How does one determine the likelihood chi-squared is accurately determining features during feature selection of categorical data? To summarize the rest of this post, the chi-squared test doesn't appear to follow a discernible pattern so how can one be sure it is not eliminating important features, or keeping spurious ones? Is there another further test one can do?

There seem to be a number of heuristics surrounding the chi-squared tests. For example, observed and expected values should be greater than or equal to 5. Also, the number of samples should be greater than 13, but not too large. I could not find a documented upper bound, but a little experimentation indicates it increases or decreases considerably with a sample size of 100, at least with my sample data. Also, I notice that many examples standardize the data prior to feature selection.

To better understand, I generated my own data as follows:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 3 | -0.967 | -98.5 | 37207417 | 32 |
| 730 | 203 | 6.829 | 213.5 | 731059944 | 731 |
| 319 | 121 | 4.652 | 116.5 | 312290199 | 319 |
| 492 | 265 | 5.396 | 434.5 | 495552794 | 494 |
| 417 | 90 | 3.515 | 50.5 | 412029676 | 420 |

Feature A matches the response, F, though with a small random difference. Feature B does not match F. Feature C matches F, but at 100th the magnitude and a random difference of up to 30%. Feature D matches F, but at half the magnitude and a random error of up to 100%. E matches F, though scaled massively and with a random error of 30%.

Without scaling, I generated chi-squared values and probabilities. A, D and E showed dependence on F with probabilities upwards of .9. D had a probability of 1!

I then standardized and scaled all the values between 0 and 1. All the features showed dependence with a probability near 1. This made some intuitive sense because I violated the heuristic of feature magnitudes >= 5.

I then finally standardized, scaled and multiplied by 100 so the features are more reasonably sized. Now only features A and E show dependence.

I then regenerated the data with the same algorithm as follows:
|A  |B  |C      |D      |E          |F
|---|---|-------|-------|-----------|--
|426|498|4.982  |165.0  |427891218  |426
|378|89 |2.565  |234.0  |370449414  |378
|264|436|1.579  |50.5   |253152641  |256
|854|219|8.429  |511.5  |847785255  |862
|443|260|3.507  |437.0  |441054258  |435

With the raw values, A, C and E show dependence upwards of 90%. This differs from the first run where A, D and E showed dependence. The standardized and scaled between 0 and 1 showed high dependence across all features again. Finally, the standardized and scaled between 0 and 100 run show A and E having high dependence.

I realize this is a long question, but again, how does one know whether the results of the chi-squared tests are at all reliable? Further, is my notion of standardizing and scaling to 100 a reasonable approach?

Thanks in Advance!

P.S. I realize my sample data violates the heuristic of 13 samples, but I wanted to keep the tables simpler for this post.

Comment: Here are a few ways to determine if a chi square test is accurate. Considering possible null and alternate hypotheses, if your significance level is too high, then you could make a type 1 error more often. Also, try a follow up analysis after a test by comparing components/contributions to let you know which cells differed the least and most from the expected values to see how well the test did if you rejected the null. Does this help?